# how do I extend battery from lacking?

Tags: battery

I wanna ask you guys about extending battery. I run precise, My laptop can't work more than 1 hour, after it's fully charged. The notification after I unplug the charger only shows 0:45. How can I work with that condition?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify: are you asking how to extend battery life? or how to get Ubuntu to display the correct remaining time on battery?

Comment: buy a new battery.

Comment: I guess How to extend battery life. My laptop can only stay for less than an hour. I tried Jupiter and it didn't work at all.

Comment: When I run 11.10, my batter can stay more for 2 hours,